# limit of $2^n/3^{n/2}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, wolfram-alpha

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^{\frac{n}{2}}}$$

I used [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to get the limit as follows:
"[lim n tends infinity 2^n/3^(n/2)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+n+tends+infinity+2%5En%2F3%5E%28n%2F2%29)".

And using L'Hospital's rule the result was:
$\displaystyle\frac{2^{n+6}}{3^{\frac{n}{2}}}$, which tends to infinity.

My question is why does 
$\displaystyle\frac{2^{n+6}}{3^{\frac{n}{2}}}$ tend to infinity?

Comment: @Wilbert: Please use mark-up.

Comment: What is mark-up?

Comment: @Wilbert: LaTeX, like you used in your first line, to make things clearer instead of relying on words like "as n goes to infinity".

Comment: Oh that was the code I used in wolfram. That's why I enclose it in a code block.

Comment: @Wilbert: Ehr, I don't think you enclosed it in a code block; it was enclosed in `$$...$$`, which produces a math display in LaTeX.

Comment: The L'Hospital part is wrong. The derivative of $2^x$ is $2^x \ln 2$, for example. (And by the way: If you didn't know how to take the limit of your original expression $2^n/3^{n/2}$, how do you know all of a sudden that $2^{n+6}/3^{n/2} \to \infty$? Computing that limit is essentially the same problem as the one you started with.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{2^n}{3^{n/2}} = \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^n$$

Comment: You should make that upper case N a lower case n.

Comment: Thanks! Could you list which properties did you use?

Comment: @Wilbert: You tell me.

Comment: @MAtt: Done. Thanks.

Comment: @Wilbert: That would be "basic arithmetic and the definition of the fractional exponents".

Comment: @Wilbert: The key is the *distributive* law for exponents - see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

**HINT** $$\rm \frac{2^n}{3^{n/2}}\ =\ \bigg(\frac{4}{3}\bigg)^{n/2}$$

This is simply the exponents analog of pulling a common factor out of a sum:

$$\rm a^n\ *\ b^{\:m\ \:n}\ \ = \ (a\ *\ b^{\:m}\:)^{\:n} $$

$$\rm a\ n +  b\ m\ n\ = \ (a + b\ m)\ n $$

So it's essentially a consequence of the *distributive* law for exponents.

The given problem is the special case $\rm\ \ \ a,b,m,n\ \to\ 1/3,\:2,\:2,\:n/2$

Comment: Thanks! I can't upvote yet because my reputation =(